# Python "in" operator not working correctly?

Tags: python, operators

The `in` function in my python script is working very strange. I have no idea if it is meant to be like this or if this is a bug in 3.3 .
Here's part of my script:

```
command = input("\ ")
if command in ['help', 'HELP', 'Help']:
        print (help)
```

1st time I tried, inputting help or HELP works while Help does not work.

Next time I tried, Help and HELP works while help does not.

Every time I try it, it will be random on what it accepts and what does not. Someone please help me if this is a bug or if something is wrong with the script.

Comment: `works while X doesn't work`. This **doesn't mean anything!**. What does "doesn't work" mean? If the output is not what you think correct, why didn't you post the actual output *and* what you'd expected? If you get an error, why didn't you post the complete traceback of the exception? If the python interpreter crashed, while didn't you provide a MWE that makes python crash? These are the **essential** information people must know in order to help; otherwise what people can do is plain guessing and saying random things.

Comment: make the code easier to debug. and keep trying different inputs. you are sure to find the bug.

Comment: I had the same problem and your question helped me find the answer! 
The problem was I was not comparing the strings case properly.

Answer (score 9):

Where is the variable `help` defined (or do you mean to use the builtin)? Perhaps the problem is that you meant to `print(command)`

Your syntax of `in` looks fine to me. But consider whether this would work just as well

```
if command.lower() == 'help':
```

Comment: its somewhere within the script. I did not put it in here.
`help = "Type exit to exit, type start to start the timer" `
Sort of like that

Comment: @ChrRubin, ok. Maybe you need to post more of the script

Answer (score 5):

The 'in' operate is fine to me, please check the value of command immediately after command = input(''), to see if the value is what you just inputed. Again, you may post more scripts or error messages here.

Answer (score 1):

```
command = input("\ ")
if command in ['help', 'HELP', 'Help']:
        print (help)
```

works for me in any case.

But i noticed that if you press Enter before entering Help, HELP or help, it is not catch. Make sure you don't add any other character like empty space or new line. Or catch you input with a regex instead of a full lenght word.