# python 'in' operator returning the wrong value

Tags: python

I ran into a weird issue with the 'in' operator for python, which is reproduced from the ipython shell below:

```
    In [119]: Teff = 10000

    In [120]: loggs = numpy.arange(4.5, 4*numpy.log10(Teff) - 15.02, -0.1)

    In [121]: 4.0 in loggs
    Out[121]: False

    In [122]: loggs
    Out[122]: 
    array([ 4.5,  4.4,  4.3,  4.2,  4.1,  4. ,  3.9,  3.8,  3.7,  3.6,  3.5,
    3.4,  3.3,  3.2,  3.1,  3. ,  2.9,  2.8,  2.7,  2.6,  2.5,  2.4,
    2.3,  2.2,  2.1,  2. ,  1.9,  1.8,  1.7,  1.6,  1.5,  1.4,  1.3,
    1.2,  1.1,  1. ])
```

As you can see, 4.0 is in the array, but the 'in' operator returns False. I tried this same thing with '4' (an integer) and '4.', both with the same result. Same with other values in that array (like 3.9). Any ideas? I am running python 2.7.1, with numpy version 1.7.0.

I saw a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16784675/python-in-operator-not-working-correctly#new-answer?newreg=5ac20c8cfed24b0e92f553e6ed727cb7) that is close, but there was never a good answer for what happened with 'in'.

Comment: Try to print `loggs[5]`, and you'll see that the actual value is `4.0000000000000018`.

Comment: Welcome in the floating world guy.

Comment: Variants of this question get asked every day

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `4.0` is not in the array.  A value very close to 4.0, but slightly off (due to floating point inaccuracies) is in the array, and when you print it, the printing routine is rounding to "4.0" for display purposes.

If you print out the actual element (`loggs[5]`), python will print with more precision, and you will see the value is actually slightly higher than `4.0` (approximately `4.0000000000000018`).

I recommend reading [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Actually 4.0 not in you array and if you want to see the true values of your array you can write:

```
loggs.tolist()
```

and you will see the values, so if you want to check 4.0 you will need to make something like this:

```
new_loggs = [round(i,2) for i in loggs.tolist()]
4.0 in new_loggs
```

output: True

Answer (score -1):

For loop the matrice with conditionals or the range you want to get from the matrice.

```
import numpy as np
Teff = 10000
loggs = np.arange(4.5, 4*np.log10(Teff) - 15.02, -0.1)
print loggs
for i in loggs:
    if i > 3.9:
        print i
```

Output: 
4.5
4.4
4.3
4.2
4.1
4.0
3.9